# I want to create a reuse model on every model but it occur error

Tags: flutter, dart

I want apiDataResponse to same as response below:

```
   ‘role_id’: ‘1’,
   ‘id’: ‘1’,
   ‘success’: true,
   ‘err_msg’: ‘error’,
}
```

every api response will return `success` and `err_msg` from dio client so i want to create a reuse model as below

```
@immutable
@freezed
abstract class SignInDataResponsee with \_$SignInDataResponse {
@JsonSerializable()
factory SignInDataResponse({
String? token,
@JsonKey(name: 'role_id') RoleStatus? roleId,
APIDataResponse apiDataResponse,
}) = \_SignInDataResponse;

factory SignInDataResponse.fromJson(Map\<String, dynamic\> json) =\>
\_$SignInDataResponseFromJson(json);
}


@immutable
@freezed
abstract class APIDataResponse with _$APIDataResponse {
  @JsonSerializable()
  const factory APIDataResponse({
    @JsonKey(name: 'err_msg') String? errMsg,
    required bool success,
  }) = _APIDataResponse;

  factory APIDataResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$APIDataResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

but flutter know it as `apiDataResponse` field from api response how can fix this

anyone can fix this?